# Training accuracy suddenly drops to zero after a while in Tensorflow?

Tags: conv-neural-network, tensorflow

I was training a ConvNet on CIFAR10 based on the code presented in "Deep MNIST for Experts" tutorial by TensorFlow. After around a few thousand epochs with training accuracy gradually increasing as expected, it suddenly drops from 90% to 4% with cross entropy and predicted scores turns into NaN. Any ideas why this happen?

My code:

```
class TensorFlowCNN(object):
def __init__(self, input_dim=(32, 32, 3), num_classes=10):
    self.input_dim = input_dim
    self.num_classes = num_classes

def model(self):
    H, W, C = self.input_dim
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, H, W, C])
    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, self.num_classes])
    # 1st conv-pool
    W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, C, 32])
    b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])
    x_image = x
    h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
    h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)
    # 2nd conv-pool
    W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
    b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])
    h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
    h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)
    # 3rd conv-pool
    W_conv3 = weight_variable([5, 5, 64, 128])
    b_conv3 = bias_variable([128])
    h_conv3 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool2, W_conv3) + b_conv3)
    h_pool3 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv3)
    # FC
    W_fc1 = weight_variable([H/8 * W/8 * 128, 1024])
    b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])
    h_pool3_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool3, [-1, H/8 * W/8 * 128])
    h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool3_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)
    # Dropout
    keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)
    # Readout
    W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 10])
    b_fc2 = bias_variable([10])
    y_conv = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2)

    return x, y_, y_conv, keep_prob

def train(self, test_data, test_labels, val_data, val_labels):
    x, y_, y_conv, keep_prob = self.model()
    sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y_conv), reduction_indices=[1]))
    train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    for i in xrange(20000):
        x_train, y_train = svhn.next_batch(100, i)
        if i % 100 == 0:
            loss = cross_entropy.eval(feed_dict={
                x: x_train, y_: y_train, keep_prob: 1.0
            })
            train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
                x: x_train, y_: y_train, keep_prob: 1.0
            })
            val_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
                x: val_data, y_: val_labels, keep_prob: 1.0
            })
            # fname = 'params/%s.txt' % i
            # np.savetxt(fname, y_conv.eval(feed_dict={x: x_train, keep_prob: 1.0}), fmt='%1.4e')
            print("step %d, loss %g, training accuracy %g, validation accuracy %g"
                  % (i, loss, train_accuracy, val_accuracy))
        train_step.run(feed_dict={x: x_train, y_: y_train, keep_prob: 0.5})

    print("test accuracy %g" % accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
        x: test_data, y_: test_labels, keep_prob: 1.0}))
```

Comment: Some more details (eg code) are crucial to make this an informative question.

Comment: @GiuseppeBiondi-Zoccai Thanks for your opinion. I added the code.